# Vector items not being added

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, dictionary

Consider the following source code:

```
map<string,vector<SectionElement *>> _sections;
...
static SharedData *_shared;
...
static int iniHandler(void* user, const char* section, const char* name,
                          const char* value)
{

        map<string,vector<SectionElement*>> iniFile = *(_shared->sections);

        auto& iniSection = iniFile[ section];
        auto sectionElement = new SectionElement();
        sectionElement->name = name;
        sectionElement->value = value;
        iniSection.push_back( sectionElement);
        return 1;
}
```

The problem with the code is that if I add an element to iniSection it works, but the vector that is retrieved from iniFile does not seem to be the same that is kept in the map. So every time the function iniHandler is called the count of the vector is zero. I am a bit at a loss here and wondering what obvious thing I am missing...

Comment: Hard to tell, without knowing what `SharedData` is, and how you're initializing `_shared` actually!

Comment: `map<string,vector<SectionElement*>> iniFile = *(_shared->sections);` This copies a map, and the map *owns* the elements, i.e. the elements get copied, too.

Comment: DyP: THANK-YOU!!!! That was the bug. I guess I was looking at the code too long. And yes it is an ugly bit of code, but the problem is that I need to integrate C code with C++ and there was no easy way around this.

Answer (score 2):

You modify a local `map` called `iniFile`. This has no effect on some other map, `*(_shared->sections)`. Perhaps you wanted to make `iniFile` a reference?

Comment: Thank-you that was the problem. I appreciate the answer.